# Full Easting and Northing coordinates values cannot be encoded in GRASS r.water.outlet in SEXTANTE-QGIS

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, sextante

The Easting or Northing coordinate parameter accepts only 5 digits.  The Easting and Northing values for my outlet are 6 and 7 digits long (integer).  How can they be encoded in r.water.outlet?  Can real numbers be encoded as well?

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a bug in the Sextante interface, the original GRASS module allows of course real east and north coordinates (see [manual](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.water.outlet.html)).
Please report this here: http://hub.qgis.org/projects/sextante/issues